# Make content automatically go into multiple pages

Tags: html

On a site such as http://failblog.org/, there are a bunch of photos with content around them. Whenever failblog uploads a new photo, it pushes the bottom photo of the first page onto the second page, and the bottom of the second onto the third, etc. How can I do this? I want to have a section of HTML (such as the contents of a <div>) automatically wrap onto multiple pages, and everything not inside the section will repeat. (As on failblog.org). Thank you.

Comment: you are talking about 'pagination'

Comment: You'll need AJAX and/or server-side scripting for this. (You can't do it with pure HTML)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you have 2 options.

### Server-Side Only

You need something called pagination to occur- when there is too much content to display on one page, server-side code can create virtual "pages" for each page of content to display.

This can't be solved with HTML, Javascript, or CSS, this depends on the server-side language (such as PHP, Ruby, Python, etc) that you are working with.

### AJAX

If you want to flip through content, though on the same page, then you might consider looking at a jQuery plugin that can do that for you. Here's a [list](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-pagination-plugins/) of plugins that look like they might suit your needs.